# Warning Package name 'uninitialized.application.id' used in: AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

My project flow is expo bare flow, am using expo SDK 42. I tried to get EAS build and Normal Android Studio to generate a Signed build but it will provide an error.(**Warning Package name 'uninitialized.application.id' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest**).  I tried to clean and rebuild, Invalidate cache and restart. but no use any suggestions to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you check this solution? https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea/issues/128#issuecomment-1031600199

Comment: thanks for your response. yeah, I tried But not worked.

Comment: @BharanitharanSakthivel For me it was running "Sync project with gradle files" that fixed it because I was on a branch with gradle version higher than current so once coming back to current branch with older gradle version, the files needed to be re-synced